# How can I distinguish a plugin from a fragment?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to find the nature of the projects in my workspace. I found the `IProject.getDescription().getNatureIds()` method. as I see, both a plug-in and a fragment have the same natures. So this is not the right way to go.

Any other ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following:

`IPluginModelBase[] workspaceModels = PDECore.getDefault().getModelManager().getWorkspaceModels();` and there is a `isFragmentModel()` method in `IPluginModelBase`